# How to make a table in tensorboard

Tags: tensorboard

I'm using Tensorboard to plot loss for my experiments.

I would also like to add test results to Tensorboard for easy experiment comparison, but I can't find the function that does that.

I just need a simple table something like:

```
| Exp name | Metric 1 | Metric 2 |
|----------|----------|----------|
| Exp 1    | 12       | 123      |
| Exp 2    | 23       | 234      |
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm using PyTorch version of `SummaryWriter`.

Comment: I think you can hack this by using text output for tensorboard. However, as far as I know there is no table feature in tf board. To better compare results you can also save a single scalar in a scalar plot under the same tag and summary file.

Comment: Nice question. I would have liked that feature in Tensorboard, but it's not there. You can look at a work-around solution posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use tensoboard to log markdown, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text

assuming someone might be interested in a pytorch solution with f-string, one might do

```
from torch.utils import tensorboard

summary_writer = tensorboard.SummaryWriter(log_dir="/tmp")
val = 0.1234
table = f"""
    | Exp name | Metric 1  | Metric 2  |
    |----------|-----------|-----------|
    | Exp 1    | {val:.2f} | {val:.2f} |
    | Exp 2    | {val:.2f} | {val:.2f} |
"""
table = '\n'.join(l.strip() for l in table.splitlines())
summary_writer.add_text("table", table, 0)
```

This will create following [tensorboard table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQeq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of this article:
https://androidkt.com/keras-confusion-matrix-in-tensorboard/

Basically display images of the table instead text.